# python@3.9: the bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be installed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have zsh and Python 3.9 installed on my MacOS but whenever I try to try something in the command line, I'm getting this kind of error:

```
brew install python@3.7  # for example
```

> Error: python@3.7: the bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be
> installed.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23):

I tried running
`xcode-select --install`
but estimated download time was over 280 hours, so I installed latest **Apple Command Line Tools** from

**[Apple Developer Downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command)**

(File was under 700MB)

After that installation, `brew upgrade python` went without a hitch.

Comment: Same here. However, in my case the time estimation decreased after a few minutes into the download to only a few minutes.

Comment: I tried many options but they does not work. Finally, I downloaded XCode and Command Line Tools from above links and they worked. Thanks so much !

Comment: I also got a crazy estimated time - and it did not drop, even after 3 or 4 minutes. This method worked for me - thanks. 

Comment: I was facing this issue while installing `aws-sam-cli`, but this solution works flawlessly. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Running this solved the problem for me:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I have installed Xcode, and run `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`. I don't want to install a standalone command line tools.

Comment: @DawnSong there are lots of things I don't want to do with mac but are forced on me. it's not a separate application from Xcode it's a separate plugin that's not included with the base until you choose to install it

Comment: @SampsonCrowley Command line tools are required by Home Brew, although it's not necessary since Xcode provided it, too.

Comment: @DawnSong this maybe a homebrew bug.

Comment: Chances are that the python bottle was compiled using Apple Command Line Tools, so some binary dependencies might be in place. Try to install from source using the `-s, --build-from-source` flag. Worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

try to delete CommandLineTools:
rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
and reinstall it:
$ xcode-select --install

I found this solution on github , Credit: Dmitry Chupahin

Answer (score 1):

If the bottle requires Apple Command Line Tools, install from sources:

```
brew install --build-from-source python@3.7
```